# RDS vs. RD - any differences in speed and quality?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, wide-area-network, rds

All other things being equal (available hardware resources, speed and type of network connection), is there any technical difference with an impact on quality between connecting to an RDS server vs. an RD on a Windows client system?

Background: I want to make an RDS test drive and only have access to a Windows client system on the listening side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same underlying technology (eg: Win7 vs Win2008R2, Win8 vs Win2012, ecc.), and using the same settings (eg: sound off, color depth 16 bit, ecc) you should have the same performance connecting both to Windows clients and Windows Servers.

Comment: Thanks Shodanshok. Yes, that would be the same. In my case Win10 vs. Server2016. Do you maybe have any kind of evidence that could back your answer? E.g. comparison of the binaries, or other measuring?

Comment: No, I think such comparison does not even exists. However, my reply was based on the educated guess that with the same library version, you should have similar performance. Moreover, the very same fact that Microsoft does not publicize a "faster RDP experience" for Win Server vs Client let me think that performance are basically the same.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, you seem to be giving exactly the evidence I asked for: "same library version". Could you elaborate on where to find this library on both systems in order to prove it's the same?

Comment: You can find the core RDP libraries under C:\Windows\System32. Here you will find rdpcore.dll and such. Comparing them on a fully patched Win7 x64 and a Win2008R2 x64, I can see they are the very same version (6.1.7601.17779)